# Minute dimension Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I checked the documentation and the way to request a minute is by 'minute' in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema#dimensions
I'm trying to request a minute dimension in the GA4 API but this error occurs:

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: InvalidArgument
400 Please remove minute to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Please remove minute to make the request compatible. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv6:%5B2800:3f0:4001:833::200a%5D:443 {grpc_message:"Please remove minute to make the request compatible. The request\'s dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/", grpc_status:3, created_time:"2023-05-09T10:37:02.0337-03:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import (
    DateRange,
    Dimension,
    Metric,
    MetricType,
    RunReportRequest,
)


def run_sample():
    """Runs the sample."""
    # TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
    #  property ID before running the sample.
    property_id = "YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"
    run_report(property_id)


def run_report(property_id="YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID"):
    """Runs a report of active users grouped by country."""
    client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()

    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        dimensions=[Dimension(name="minute")],
        metrics=[Metric(name="activeUsers")],
        date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2020-09-01", end_date="2020-09-15")],
    )
    response = client.run_report(request)
```

`